# Auto fill-in data (input field) from MySQL Database in PHP (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, html, pdo

**This post contains:**

- 3 PHP pages
- MySQL table picture
- Picture of the form

---

As the title says, I need to **extract** some **information** **from** my **database**.

**So far I have the following:**

- **Index page** <-- You need to login here with a personal code. (this is where I get the 'Session username' from that already works at the contact page)
- **Config page** <-- Used for database access and all
- **Contact page** <-- In here I would like to auto fill-in the users data.

**Database table consists of:**

- username; email; realName (and some other stuff I don't need here)

So in the contact page I would like to see the following:

- Card number = username (this already works)
- Auto fill-in: realName and email according to the username.

---

*Maybe it is possible to extract the info when logging in and storing these in the POST variable already? But how?*

---

**Database:**

- **Table** I need to use: **'members'**

[image: members]

---

The info given by the user himself/herself = *username*

The info I need to auto fill-in = *realName* and *email*

---

**Picture of the form.**

The email should be in the SESSION statement, so I can send a confirmation email to the person, and the realName should be entered from the database.

[image: Picture of the form]

---

**These are the files currently running:**

config.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','*****');
define('DBUSER','*****');
define('DBPASS','*****');
define('DBNAME','*****');

//application address
define('DIR','http://*****/');
define('SITEEMAIL','noreply@*****');

try {

//create PDO connection
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
//show error
echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
exit;
}

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
$user = new User($db);
?>
```

contact form:

```
<?php require('includes/config.php'); 

//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: index.php'); } 
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>*****</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"        />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script  src="siteassets/assets/js/ie/shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="siteassets/assets/css/main.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="siteassets/assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#next').keyup(calculate);
$('#nextprice').keyup(calculate);
$('#current').keyup(calculate);
$('#currentprice').keyup(calculate);
});
 function calculate(e)
{
$('#total').val($('#next').val() * $('#nextprice').val() + $('#current').val() * $('#currentprice').val());
}
</script>

</head>
<body class="landing">
    <div id="page-wrapper">

        <!-- Header -->
            <header id="header" class="alt">

                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon fa-angle-down">Menu</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="home.php">Current Project</a></li>
                                <li><a href="newproj.php">Next Projects</a></li>
                                <li><a href="prev.php">Previous Projects</a></li>
                                <li><a href="who.php">Who are we?</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php" class="button">contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>

        <!-- Banner -->
            <section id="banner">
                <h2>*****</h2>
                <p>Slogan.</p>
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><a href="home.php" class="button">Current Project</a></li>
                    <li><a href="newproj.php" class="button">Next Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="prev.php" class="button">Previous Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="who.php" class="button">Who are we?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php" class="button special">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </section>

        <!-- Main -->




            <section id="main" class="container 75%">
                <div class="box">
<? 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{ 
if(strlen($_POST['name2']) == 0)
{ $error_msg ="- Please, provide us with your name.<br>"; } 

if(!empty($error_msg))
{ 
//Een van de velden werd niet goed ingevuld 
echo "<b>Your message can't be send due to the following reason:</b>    <br><br>"; 
echo $error_msg; 
echo "<br>Click on <a href='javascript:history.back(1)'>Go back</a> and  provide us with your name.<br><br>"; 
}
else 
{ 
$recipient = "*****"; 
$subject = "******"; 
$header = "From: " . $_POST['uwemail'] . "\n"; 
$mail_body = "Contact script werd op " . date("d-m-Y") . " om " . date("H:i") . " uur uitgevoerd.\n"; 
$mail_body .= "*****:\n\n"; 
$mail_body .= "Naam: " . $_POST['name2'] . "\n"; 
$mail_body .= "Met als kaartnummer: " . $_POST['card2'] . "\n"; 
$mail_body .= "******: " .  $_POST['current2'] . "\n"; 
$mail_body .= "******: " .  $_POST['next2'] . "\n"; 
$mail_body .= "Voor een totaal van: " . $_POST['total2'] . " EUR.";   
$mail_body .= "\n\n -- ****** --"; 
mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header); 
print "<b>IMPORTANT!</b>";
print "<br><br>*****.";
print "<br><br>***** ";
print $_POST['total2'];
print " *****";
print "<br><br>******.";
print "<br><br>******";
}
} 
else 
{ 
?>      
        <form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" name="contact">
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                            Your personal card number
                                <input type="text" name="card2" id="card" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" placeholder="Card Number" readonly/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                            Please enter your name. (mandatory)
                                <input type="text" name="name2"  id="name" value="" placeholder="Your name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                            Current Project - Smile
                                <input type="text" name="current2" id="current" value="" placeholder="How many tickets would you like?" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                            Next Project - Sand
                                <input type="text" name="next2" id="next" value="" placeholder="How many tickets would you like?" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                <input type="hidden" id="currentprice" value="10" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                <input type="hidden" id="nextprice" value="10" placeholder="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                        <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                                            <input name="uwemail" placeholder="Email" type="hidden" value="******"/>
                                        </div>
                        <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                        Total price.(In EUR)
                                <input type="text" name="total2" id="total" value=""  readonly/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row uniform">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <ul class="actions align-center">
                                    <li><input type="submit" name="submit"value="Place Order"/></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>


<?php 
} 
?> 

                </div>
            </section>


        <!-- Footer -->
            <footer id="footer">

                <ul class="copyright">
                    <li>&copy; *****. All rights reserved.</li>
                </ul>
            </footer>

    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="siteassets/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="siteassets/assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
        <script src="siteassets/assets/js/jquery.scrollgress.min.js"></script>
        <script src="siteassets/assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="siteassets/assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="siteassets/assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="siteassets/assets/js/main.js"></script>




</body>
</html>
```

Index page (where they have to login)

```
<?php
//include config
require_once('includes/config.php');


//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: home.php');
    exit;

} else {
    $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
}

}//end if submit


?>

<html>
<head>



    <title>******</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"     />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/iv.js"></script><!    [endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css"     /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css"     /><![endif]-->
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" />        </noscript>
</head>
<body class="is-loading">

    <!-- Wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Main -->
                <section id="main">
                    <header>

                        <h1>*****</h1>
                        <h1><a style="color:#FFFFFF" href=''>Coming soon.</a></h1>



<div class="container">

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
        <form role="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
            <h2>Please Login</h2>

            <hr>

            <?php
            //check for any errors
            if(isset($error)){
                foreach($error as $error){
                    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
                }
            }

            if(isset($_GET['action'])){

                //check the action
                switch ($_GET['action']) {
                    case 'active':
                        echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Your account is now active you may now log in.</h2>";
                        break;
                    case 'reset':
                        echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Please contact us for a new card.</h2>";
                        break;
                    case 'resetAccount':
                        echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Password changed, you may now login.</h2>";
                        break;
                }

            }


            ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username"     class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter your card number" value="    <?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" tabindex="1">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" value="*****" tabindex="3" >
            </div>

<br>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit"    name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg"     tabindex="5"></div>
            </div>
<hr>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                     <a style="color:#FFFFFF" href='*********'>Lost your card? Contact us.</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>



</div>




                    </header>

                </section>

            <!-- Footer -->
                <footer id="footer">
                    <ul class="copyright">
                        <li>&copy; ******</li>
                    </ul>
                </footer>

        </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"> </script><![endif]-->
        <script>
            if ('addEventListener' in window) {
                window.addEventListener('load', function() {  document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(/\bis-loading\b/,  ''); });
                document.body.className +=  (navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE|rv:11\.0)/) ? ' is-ie' : '');
            }
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use a WHERE clause and SELECT the columns in question in a loop. This being a blind shot at unknown db schema and MySQL API used to connect with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

In the user.php file I had everything prepared already, but I just didn't understand why it didn't work.

Turned out to be a simple error XD

```
<?php
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

private $_db;
function __construct($db){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_db = $db;
}
private function get_user_hash($username){
    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID, realName, email FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));
        return $stmt->fetch();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
}
public function login($username,$password){
    $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);
    if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
        $_SESSION['realName'] = $row['realName']; 
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];  
        return true;
    }
}

public function logout(){
    session_destroy();
}

public function is_logged_in(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true)    {
        return true;
    }
}
}
?>
```

I forgot to add the realName and email to this line: (idiot me :D)

```
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID, realName, email FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
```

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: Since you're having user class (ex.: `$user->is_logged_in()`), then in `$_POST[]` method ignore `$_POST['name2']` as it can still be changed through DEV tools and instead change that to `$_SESSION['username']` (assuming that's the correct value). This is much more reliable than using HTML field. The PHP part (of query) also differs because you're using PDO, but I can't help with this one because I'm using `mysqli_`, not PDO (sorry about that), but query itself should be similar.

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `number` = '".$_POST['number']."'"
```

But don't forget to [escape your string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), otherwise, your query is vulnerable.

Comment: Hey, 
What info would you like?

Comment: You should provide your PHP code that is related to your problem.

Comment: OP states: *"If I'm looking for (for example) number: 'AB123'"* - `= $_POST['number']` will fail here, as it needs to be quoted since it's a string. Plus, that also leaves them open to an SQL injection. The question is way too unclear also. You're in for a probable long haul on this one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Right, I missed that. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: Youre welcome Edvin. I edited my comment though; about being in for a probably long haul. I hope you won't though, but I'll upvote.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the help and upvote. I'm probably not going to stay here until OP adds more information (so I could narrow down the answer).

Comment: Added 2 pages, I hope these will be sufficient?

Comment: @J.DKYSR I have edited the answer but it doesn't completely answer your question (since I'm not using PDO), sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the edit mate, I'll keep googling till I find it, or till someone knows it for me ;).

Comment: Since you're using PDO already, perhaps you can try to slowly build it? I mean, there is a lot of information already provided (in your code too).